# Code failing to run print inside a user designed function

Tags: python

Over the course of developing a dice rolling application as a way to test how well I can code I came across an error with the printing of final results. The section of code that seems to be causing the issue is a function used to actually roll said dice. I wanted to ask if the issue is a specific weird part of the code or if it is a common thing within pythononic functions and that it was easy thing to correct.

Context for the code, the function is passed a argument (I think that's the right word, still learning to code and many resources are a bit wordy) in the form xdy (with x being number of dice and y being the sides, d is just inserted to differentiate both in code and RL).

It should ideally output an array of the dice results and the number that are 5 or above. Currently it succeeds in rolling and returning the dice in an array but as stated above fails to print the number of 5 or above dice.

Code:

```
def atributeCheck():
    rolls = dice.split(",")
    dice = []
    for i in rolls:
        tmp = i.split("d")
        for i in range(int(tmp[0])))
            currentDie = randint(1, int(tmp[1]))
            dice.append(currentDie)
            if currentDie >= 5:
            hits += 1
    return dice
    print(hits ,"hits")
```

I can't take credit for much of the code, most of it was from a personal friend with me adapting it to better suit the rest of the program. Just ask if more context is needed

Comment: Your code is not a MCVE - it depends on globals that are not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return breaks you out of the method, statements after a return are never executed. 
You should put the print before the the return statement.

Comment: Thanks,seems to work but for some reason now the return isn't working. Similear issue or would this be diffrent?